# Spring ClassNotFoundException upon bean creation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, titan, intellij-14

I'm want to use the class TitanGraph in my IntelliJ project. I therefore included all necessary libraries in my project. The project compiles just fine, but as soon as Spring tries to create a bean with this class type, it throws a ClassNotFoundException.
My bean:

```
public class GraphEngineGlue {
    @Bean
    public TitanGraph titanGraph() {
        return TitanFactory.open(configuration);
    }
}
```

In my XML file I have the following reference:

```
<bean class="my.package.GraphEngineGlue"/>
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible that some libraries are not included at runtime?

EDIT:

stacktrace

```
3664 [main        ] ERROR com.mypackage.web.spring.BootstrapAwareContextLoaderListener - Unexpected error during initialization, cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanGraph
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: com.mypackage.GraphEngineGlue
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:368)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:244)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:694)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:633)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
    at com.mypackage
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at com.mypackage
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:782)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at com.mypackage
    at com.mypackage
    at com.mypackage
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.mypackage.Main(Main.java:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/thinkaurelius/titan/core/TitanGraph
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2693)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1967)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.addAllMethods(ReflectUtils.java:348)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.getMethods(Enhancer.java:421)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:456)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:377)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:317)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.createClass(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:125)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.enhance(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:98)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:358)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanGraph
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 52 more
```

Comment: Please add the stacktrace

Comment: Also you should add them to Deployment Assembly

Comment: I added a stacktrace. All libraries were added, through Project Settings -> Modules ->  MyModule -> Dependencies ->  + -> Select jars -> Apply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)i don't think that's the cause, but if you define the bean in a java configuration as you do, then you don't need to define it an xml based configuration as well.

2)check that you included the dependency in the correct scope, i don't know if you are using maven or ivy or whatnot but if the dependency is set to be available only for testing for example and you run the app as a main method and not in a testing context then you will not have the class available.

Comment: My dependencies were not included in the classpath because the folder of the dependencies was not.

Comment: So is it solved? you should answer your question then :)